# How is the hierarchy of .htm/.html/.php decided?

Tags: web-development

If I have a folder with files named index.html, index.htm, and index.php how it is decided which one will be used if you only list the URL to that folder? Is that something you can chose or is that up to the host?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If using Apache, it's the order the filenames are given in the [`DirectoryIndex`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_dir.html)  directive. WAMP's default is

```
<IfModule dir_module>
    DirectoryIndex index.html index.php index.php3 index.htm
</IfModule>
```

where `index.html` will be served if it exists, then `index.php`, and so on.

Comment: Also, on hosts where you don't have direct access to the full Apache config, you can sometimes override their settings by [placing a similar rule in htaccess](http://www.htaccess-guide.com/directoryindex-uses/). Some may also let you do this through the control panel. It's best to contact them directly or use their knowledge base/forums for specifics.

Comment: Nice addition, @Su'.